# User groups have more permissions than given

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm having the problem that sharepoint 2013 is giving more permissions (like: editing files while having restricer read or view only etc.).

Changing the permission level doenst work.

Comment: Please check whether permission is not given at the Webapplication level?

Answer (score 0):

Use the check permission feature of SharePoint for particular user and you will be able to see from where user is geting edit permission or extra permission you are referring to.

---

Check permissions for a user or group for a site

Open the SharePoint site on which you want to check permissions.

On the Site Actions menu  Button image , click Site Settings.

On the Site Settings page, under Users and Permissions, click Check Effective permissions.

On the Check Effective Permissions page, in the User/Group box, type the e-mail address of the user or distribution group for which you want to verify permissions, and then click the Check Names icon.

Click Check Now.

---

Reference link - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-permissions-for-a-user-or-group-13d15c92-1dea-4aad-a665-4c3d1d377850

Thanks.

Comment: The permissions were set correct according to the check effective permissions page. It seems that it is only on the homepage which is also the sitecollection. On the other sites everything works fine with the permissions they are given

Comment: Please share more details then, screenshot of effective permission pages, and the screenshot of page where user is able to edit though having restricted read/view only.

Comment: Hmm i dont know how. but we created a new group and put the users in there. and now it does work. Isnt really an answer but it does the job now.

Comment: :)...ok edit your question and provide steps you did so that it can be helpful to others...!